# Is it possible to make json4s not to throw exception when required field is missing?

Tags: scala, json4s

Is it possible to make json4s not to throw exception when required field is missing ?

When I "extract" object from raw json string it throws exception like this one

```
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for pager
No usable value for rpp
Did not find value which can be converted into byte
    at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:98)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.org$json4s$Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$buildCtorArg(Extraction.scala:388)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$11.apply(Extraction.scala:396)
```

Is it possible just to let it be null ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's quite simple, you have to use `Option` and its potentials, `Some` and `None`.

```
val json = ("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> Some(35));
val json = ("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> (None: Option[Int]))
```

Beware though, in the above case a `match` will be performed for your `Option`. If it's `None`, it will be completely removed from the string, so it won't feed back null.

In the same pattern, to parse incomplete JSON, you use a `case class` with `Option`.

```
case class someModel(
    age: Option[Int],
    name: Option[String]
);
val json = ("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> None);
parse(json).extract[someModel];
```

There is a method which won't throw any exception, and that is `extractOpt`

```
parse(json).extractOpt[someModel];
```

A way to replicate that with the scala API would be to use `scala.util.Try`:

```
Try { parse(json).extract[someModel] }.toOption
```

Answer (score 7):

I've dealt with this problem when dealing with data migrations, and I wanted default values to fill undefined fields.

My solution was to merge the defaults into the JValue before extracting the result.

```
  val defaultsJson = Extraction.decompose(defaults)
  val valueJson = JsonUtil.jValue(v)
  (defaultsJson merge valueJson).extract[T]
```

JsonUtil.scala

```
  import org.json4s._

  object JsonUtil {
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    import java.io.{InputStreamReader, ByteArrayInputStream}

    def jValue(json: String): JValue = {
      jValue(json.getBytes(UTF_8))
    }

    def jValue(json: Array[Byte]): JValue = {
      val reader = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(json), UTF_8)
      native.JsonParser.parse(reader)
    }
  }
```