# scala json4s create json with optional/nullable field throws exception

Tags: scala, parser-combinators, json4s

I am fairly new to scala and functional programming. I have this piece of code written by someone which constructs json using [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) library,

```
val json = "body" -> ...toList.map {
  case (title, attrs) =>
    ("name", tag) ~ ("attributes", attrs)
}
val finalJson = compact(render(json))
```

All i understood on seeing this is, it constructs a json with given fields.

If `attrs` has value then its constructs json body with name and attributes.
But if `attrs` is null, then I get below exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at org.json4s.JsonDSL$class.map2jvalue(JsonDSL.scala:71)
  at org.json4s.JsonDSL$.map2jvalue(JsonDSL.scala:61)
```

Searched several so posts and couldnt get hold of how to get it working.
Closest one i got is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943957/is-it-possible-to-make-json4s-not-to-throw-exception-when-required-field-is-miss)

I think I have to utilize `None` and `Option`. Any ideas on how to fix this and probably an explanation would be really helpful if i misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using getOrElse as below:

```
val json = "body" -> ...toList.map {
case (title, attrs) =>
("name", tag) ~ ("attributes", Option(attrs).getOrElse("")))
}
val finalJson = compact(render(json))
```

Comment: attrs doesn't has getOrElse method. Can u explain a bit on how to implement using Option and use it in here.

Comment: Please see edit. I am assuming that the toList method in: "body" -> ...toList.map      produces tuples in which the second element of tuple (attrs) could be "null"